# is there any command which converts my etc/password/ file into etc/shadow/ file?

Tags: linux, encryption

I need to convert my `/etc/password` file into `/etc/shadow`.
I found this command for manually generating password in shadow.
`openssl passwd -6 -salt xyz  yourpass`

but I need to convert my `/etc/password` to `/etc/shadow`, is there any command for that?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow are only linked by one thing: the username. In fact, most entries in /etc/passwd do not have a password (accounts used to run specific apps, but without the ability to login), and giving them one could pose a security risk.

Comment: Do you mean `/etc/passwd`? There are no passwords stored in `/etc/passwd`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is. Read `man pwconv`.

Comment: Could you give an example showing how this utility is used, given their mentioning of `openssl`?